# How to apply texture pattern to 3D bars in pdf generated using iReport?

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport

I have a requirement like applying texture pattern to the 3D bars in 3D Barchart using ireport. I am able to see the texture pattern in the default JRViewer. But when I take the PDF from the same report, I cannot see the texture pattern instead I can see a transparent 3D bars.

Can someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a little research we found the answer. There is an option in the iReport for the charts called **renderType**. We need to set this as **svg**(Scalable Vector Graphics).
So the texture pattern will apply to the PDF also.

The disadvantage of using this is - The PDF file size gets increased.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This looks like a helpful answer, so I'm voting it up by clicking on the top orange triangle. If nothing better comes along, feel free to accept it by clicking on the green check mark.